# How to SELECT from a comma spliced database string - SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
            String name = null;
            String keyword2 = null;
            String author = "John";
            PreparedStatement stmt3 = DBM.conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `timelines` LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.UserID = timelines.TimelineOwner WHERE " +
                    " `TimelineName` = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), `TimelineName`) AND `Keywords` = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), `Keywords`) and `UserName` = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), `UserName`);") ;
            stmt3.setString(1, name);
            stmt3.setString(2, keyword2);
            stmt3.setString(3, author);
            List<Timeline> list = DBM.getFromDB(stmt3, new Timeline());
```

Here above is my search query for MySQL database and all is fine except there is one addition to it that I would like to add but I am lost in how to code it.

The thing is that the keywords are stored in a comma spliced String in the database and when I change the keyword parameter to, i.e "Rome", it should return that Timeline but it does not because the database String is Rome, Ceasar, Sun...... How can I add to the query so that when it comes to the Keywords column - it should compare the parameter to the words individually?

UPDATE: Maybe I can use FIND_IN_SET() and if the return from that is bigger than 0 then return its a match?

Comment: State what strings you want to compare

Comment: Have you thought about using a stored procedure to run this rather than running it front end?

Comment: Is there any reason why you use comma seperated strings instead of a 1:N relation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL LIKE operator to search for a specific keyword in the comma separated string:

`SELECT * FROM 'timelimes' WHERE 'keywords' LIKE %Rome%`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `timelines` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.UserID = timelines.TimelineOwner 
WHERE `TimelineName` = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), `TimelineName`) 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Keywords`, ',', 1), `Keywords`)
  AND `UserName` = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), `UserName`);
```

or with the operator `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `timelines` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.UserID = timelines.TimelineOwner 
WHERE `TimelineName` = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), `TimelineName`) 
  AND CONCAT(',', `Keywords`, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', COALESCE(?, '%'), ',%')  
  AND `UserName` = COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), `UserName`);
```